# How to custom sort a list in Java

Tags: java, list, sorting, collections

Lets say I have a list called `numbersList` contains these elements:
[
101,
102, . .
196,
201,
202, . .
296,
301,
302, . .
396, . .
15601,
15602, . .
15696
]

I want to sort it so that it becomes something like this:
[
101,
201,
301,
15601,
102,
202,
302,
15602, . .
196,
296,
396,
15696
]

Note that each group will always end on the 96th number. that means i will always have from x01 to x96 where x is a long value.

I tried to use some loop statements to do it but i couldn't get anywhere because i don't know how many group i will have in the list, that is why i couldn't find a suitable loop for it.

This is my failed attempt :(

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < numbersList.size() ; i = i + groups-1) {
    numbersList2.add(numbersList.get(i));
    for (int j = 0 ; j == groups - 1; j++) {
        int k = i + 96;
        numbersList2.add(numbersList.get(k));
    }
}
```

The `group` variable tells me how many groups will the user input.

Answer (score 0):

This may help:

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(101, 102, 103, 201, 202, 203, 295, 296, 301, 302, 303, 304, 396);
list.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    int v1 = o1 % 100;
    int v2 = o2 % 100;
    if (v1 < v2) {
        return -1;
    } else if (v1 == v2) {
        return o1.compareTo(o2);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
});
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list.toArray()));
```

Gives:

```
[101, 201, 301, 102, 202, 302, 103, 203, 303, 304, 295, 296, 396]
```

Comment: Yeah i thought of this. but i don't know if the entered values will always be in the hundreds. lets say the user inputted 100096, did u get me? sorry for my English

Comment: Okay... you wrote in the question: `Note that each **hundred** group will always .....` 100096%100=96 too. If it is the case, you may better provide your examples to cover that case, what would be the expected order after the sort

Comment: oh yes, my bad. I will edit it now

Comment: I edited it with more info.

Comment: @AwniAhmed my method gives the expected result: for example: `[101, 201, 301, 15601, 102, 202, 302, 15602, 196, 296, 396, 15696]` can you pls test your real data with it?

Comment: woah, it actually worked. I didn't expect that tbh. thank you very much <3

Comment: @AwniAhmed glad to hear that. Please accept the answer if it solves your problem. thx.

Answer (score 0):

Chained comparator may be used here to sort by the remainder by modulo 100 and then by the number:

```java
List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(401, 101, 602, 102, 103, 196, 201, 202, 205, 296, 301, 302, 396, 15601, 15602,15696);

data.sort(Comparator.<Integer>comparingInt(x -> x % 100)
                    .thenComparingInt(x -> x)
);

// or this shorter form
data.sort(Comparator.comparing((Integer x) -> x % 100).thenComparing(x -> x));

System.out.println(data);
```

Output:

```java
[101, 201, 301, 401, 15601, 102, 202, 302, 602, 15602, 103, 205, 196, 296, 396, 15696]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom comparator such as below.  Use the modulus operator % to get the remainder of interest using the appropriate divisor (in your example: 100 since your primary sort order is by last 2 digits) for primary comparison and the number as is for secondary comparison

```
List<Integer> src = new ArrayList<>(List.of(101, 201, 301, 15601, 102, 202, 302, 15602, 196, 296, 396, 15696));
Comparator<Integer> cmp = (i1, i2) -> {
    int v = Integer.compare(i1 % 100, i2 % 100);
    return v == 0 ? Integer.compare(i1, i2) : v;
};
Collections.sort(src, cmp);
System.out.println(src);
```

prints: [101, 201, 301, 15601, 102, 202, 302, 15602, 196, 296, 396, 15696]